# Persist the position of dragged and dropped items in a list view for next Launch

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I am using a list View in which i am dragging and dropping the list items but when i close that activity and relaunch the same list activity, the items gets restored at the same positions as in the database, how and when should i update my database for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extra 'index' field in your database to store the position, and then order the query using it. The onStop() method of your activity or fragment would be a good place to update those indexes in your data base.